# AS3 - zooming in and out with mousewheel at mouse position

Tags: actionscript-3, zooming, mousewheel

I'm making a little game for school that takes place in space. I have multiple stars with orbiting planets. Moving around is slow as it's hard to see where the other stars are, so i decided that zooming in and out is an easy way to resolve this problem.

I've placed the stars and their planet children inside an objectHolder movieclip. I can move this movieclip to simulate the planets and stars moving.

To zoom in and out, i used scaleX and scaleY together with the mousewheel.delta event. This works, but it scales around the top left part of the objectHolder movieclip.

I have absolutely no idea as of how to aproach this problem. Google got me some answers, but non seemed to work for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: if you attach some code i can help you (the part where you handle zooming)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some math here. Get the localx and localy, multiple or divide it by the zoom factor (in this case scalex and scaley) and then move the objectHolder with respect to the calculation.